# AngularJS bootstrap's carousel doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, angular-ui-bootstrap

**SOLVED**: Here it is codepen link with correct code: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/paolopolix/pen/Wwdwbr)

my angular bootstrap carousel shows images one on the other statically without "sliding", anyone know why?

This is my setup:

**HOME.HTML:**

```
<div id="slides_control">
 <div>
  <carousel interval="myInterval">
   <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
    <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}">
   </slide>
  </carousel>
 </div>
</div>
```

**APP.JS**

```
angular.module('lbda', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'lbda.controllers']).
 config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider.
    when('/home', {
     templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
     controller: 'CarouselCtrl'
   }).
   otherwise({
    redirectTo: ('/home')
   });
  }
 ]);
```

**CAROUSEL.JS**

```
angular.module('lbda.controllers').
  controller('CarouselCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.active = 0;
    $scope.myInterval = 2000;
    $scope.slides = [
      {image: '../../images/carousel/1.jpg'},
      {image: '../../images/carousel/2.jpg'}
    ];
  })
```

Comment: Could you add a plunker or fiddle which demos the problem?

Comment: Edited, here is the link: http://codepen.io/paolopolix/pen/Wwdwbr

Answer (score 1):

Below the `ng-repeat`, you'll need anchor links for the arrows:

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>

<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

You'll also need an `id` for your carousel: `#myCarousel`.

Comment: I've solved the problem (updated codepen: http://codepen.io/paolopolix/pen/Wwdwbr).
But now transitions doesn't work and the text goes under the slides... why?

Comment: It seems you were mixing up ui-bootstrap and normal bootstrap. I haven't used ui-bootstrap either, so it wasn't working.

Comment: Yes.. I just used wrong tags 'carousel','slide' instead of 'uib-carousel' and 'uib-slide'.. Any idea for the other probs?

Comment: Solved!
For transitions: I was missing the 'ngAnimate' dependency on the app.js;
For text: I was using wrong css code.

Thanks anyway! :)